# ZeroMQ(JeroMQ) receive calls cause java gc cycles

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jeromq

I am evaluating ZeroMQ as a candidate for a low latency project. But I could not find a way to stop GC cycles which are causing from pure java implementation recv calls. Is there any way to tell ZeroMQ to use same byte buffer for synchronous reads?

```
private static ZContext context;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    try
    {
        context = new ZContext();
        ZFrame qFrame = new ZFrame(queryBuffer);

        // Socket to talk to clients
        ZMQ.Socket socket = context.createSocket(SocketType.REQ);
        socket.connect(ConnectionUtils.tcp(serverIp, serverPort));
        
        //socket.setHWM(1000);
        //socket.setReceiveBufferSize(2000);
        //socket.setLinger(1000);
        //socket.setRcvHWM(1000);
        int i = 0;
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
        {
            qFrame.sendAndKeep(socket, 0);

            socket.recv(0);
            // ZFrame f= ZFrame.recvFrame(socket,0);
            // f.destroy();
            //ZMsg answer=ZMsg.recvMsg(socket,0);
            //answer.destroy();
            //socket.recvByteBuffer(answerBuf,0);
            // answerBuf.clear();

            i++;
        }
    }
```

}

[image]

Comment: what does gc has to do with `zeromq` here? you allocated? you get GC calls

Comment: I try different method signatures . Pass static byte arrays to recv  methods. But it seems zeromq allocating new byte buffers during recv calls. I am trying to find a way to tell zeromq not to allocate new byte buffers.

Comment: Basically i want to allocate a fixed buffer for recv calls. But socket api somehow creating new objects which eventually causing gc.

Comment: I don't know much about zeromq, but you need to provide the example you are using ( exactly ) that gets that screenshot.

Comment: @Eugene I do a simple request reply server/client and problem continue. I think this is the situation for very basic example. For example codes  https://github.com/auengine/zeromq